# Executing the wrong block in if-statement

Tags: python, python-2.7, if-statement

```
clothes_total = tot1 + tot2 + tot3 + tot4+ tot5
tot_price = tax * (clothes_total + shipping + gift_number)
tot_price1 = tax * (clothes_total * 0.85 + shipping + gift_number)
tot_price2 = tax * (clothes_total * 0.85 + shipping + gift_number - 30)
print "<h4>Original Price: $ %s </h4>" % clothes_total
if clothes_total < 150:
    print "<h4> TOTAL : %s </h4>" % tot_price
elif clothes_total > 150:
    print "15% Discount: $"
    print clothes_total * 0.85
    print "<h4> FIFTEEN: $ %s </h4>" % tot_price1
elif clothes_total > 200:
    print "15% Discount + $30 off: $"
    print 0.85 * (clothes_total - 30)
    print "<h4> THIRTY: $ %s </h4>" % tot_price2
```

Even though the `clothes_total` number will be greater than 200, the values in `elif clothes_total >200` would not show up. Can you guys tell me why it doesn't show up? In `elif clothes_total > 150` everything shows up nicely even if the number if greater than 200. Whatam I doing wrong?

Comment: You also need to consider the condition of clothes_total equals to 150. Currently your codes don't handle this condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because your program execution goes through `elif clothes_total > 150` before it even considers the `elif clothes_total > 200`. Here's how if-statements work:

This:

```
if condition1:
    do thing1
elif condition2:
    do thing2
elif condition2:
    do thing3
```

is the same as this:

```
if condition1:
    do thing1
else:
    if condition2:
        do thing2
    else:
        if condition2:
            do thing3
```

If you want to execute what's inside the `if clothes_total > 150` and the `if clothes_total > 200`, there are four options:

**Option 1** (just add everything from one onto the other):

```
if clothes_total < 150:
    print "<h4> TOTAL : %s </h4>" % tot_price
elif 150 < clothes_total < 200: # define a maximum as well
    print "15% Discount: $"
    print clothes_total * 0.85
    print "<h4> FIFTEEN: $ %s </h4>" % tot_price1
    print "15% Discount + $30 off: $"
    print 0.85 * (clothes_total - 30)
    print "<h4> THIRTY: $ %s </h4>" % tot_price2
elif clothes_total > 200:
    print "15% Discount + $30 off: $"
    print 0.85 * (clothes_total - 30)
    print "<h4> THIRTY: $ %s </h4>" % tot_price2
```

**Option 2** (nested if-statement):

```
if clothes_total < 150:
    print "<h4> TOTAL : %s </h4>" % tot_price
elif 150 < clothes_total:
    print "15% Discount: $"
    print clothes_total * 0.85
    print "<h4> FIFTEEN: $ %s </h4>" % tot_price1
    if clothes_total > 200:
        print "15% Discount + $30 off: $"
        print 0.85 * (clothes_total - 30)
        print "<h4> THIRTY: $ %s </h4>" % tot_price2
elif clothes_total > 200:
    print "15% Discount + $30 off: $"
    print 0.85 * (clothes_total - 30)
    print "<h4> THIRTY: $ %s </h4>" % tot_price2
```

**Option 3** (no `else`, just `if`s):

```
if clothes_total < 150:
    print "<h4> TOTAL : %s </h4>" % tot_price
if 150 < clothes_total
    print "15% Discount: $"
    print clothes_total * 0.85
    print "<h4> FIFTEEN: $ %s </h4>" % tot_price1
if clothes_total > 200:
    print "15% Discount + $30 off: $"
    print 0.85 * (clothes_total - 30)
    print "<h4> THIRTY: $ %s </h4>" % tot_price2
```

This will execute the last two `if` blocks, which might not be what you want. Note however, that in executing all those if-statments' conditions, you lose on runtime, especially if they're complex conditions

**Option 4** (range conditions):

```
if clothes_total < 150:
    print "<h4> TOTAL : %s </h4>" % tot_price
elif 150 < clothes_total < 200: # define the bounds of the range of acceptable values
    print "15% Discount: $"
    print clothes_total * 0.85
    print "<h4> FIFTEEN: $ %s </h4>" % tot_price1
elif clothes_total > 200:
    print "15% Discount + $30 off: $"
    print 0.85 * (clothes_total - 30)
    print "<h4> THIRTY: $ %s </h4>" % tot_price2
```

This gives you the short-circuiting of if-statements that you desire, as well as the guarantee that only one block will be entered at any given time.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you inspectG4dget!

Comment: Your options will fail for `clothes_total = 150` and `clothes_total = 200`.

Answer (score 1):

That's because `if-elif-else` conditions short-circuit, if first `elif` condition is `True` the second one is not going to be checked.

From [docs](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#if) on `if-suite`:

```
if_stmt ::=  "if" expression ":" suite
             ( "elif" expression ":" suite )*
             ["else" ":" suite]
```

> It selects exactly one of the suites by evaluating the expressions one
>   by one **until one is found to be true**; then that suite is executed (and
>   **no other part of the if statement is executed or evaluated**). If all
>   expressions are false, the suite of the **else** clause, if present, is
>   executed.

Use all `if`'s in case you want all conditions to be executed:

```
if clothes_total < 150:
    ...
if clothes_total > 150:
    ...
if clothes_total > 200:
  ...
```

Another option is:

```
if clothes_total < 150:
    ...
elif 150 <= clothes_total <= 200:  #this is True if clothes_total is between 150 and 200(both inclusive)
    ...
elif clothes_total > 200:          #True if clothes_total is greater than 200
  ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. If I do 'if' statement, does either one of the values from the if statement come out?

Comment: @JasonAhn If you use all `if`'s then all conditions are going to be checked.

Comment: @JasonAhn I've added another option.

Answer (score 0):

Did you know that you can sum lists:

`clothes_total = sum([tot1, tot2, tot3, tot4, tot5])`

But I *have* to believe you have a list of your total variables going, in which case you can just do:

`clothes_total = sum(totals_list)`

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, once the `total>150` condition is true the `total>200` will not even be evaluated.

Try reversing the order of the statements like this...

```
if clothes_total > 200:
    print "15% Discount + $30 off: $"
    print 0.85 * (clothes_total - 30)
    print "<h4> THIRTY: $ %s </h4>" % tot_price2
elif clothes_total > 150:
    print "15% Discount: $"
    print clothes_total * 0.85
    print "<h4> FIFTEEN: $ %s </h4>" % tot_price1
else:
    print "<h4> TOTAL : %s </h4>" % tot_price
```

Also keep in mind that in your original code a value of exactly 150 would have been missed unless you change the `<` to `<=`.